# Node locale not working as expected

Tags: node.js, locale

```
> new Date().toLocaleString();
'1/12/2018, 4:20:34 PM'
> new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB');
'1/12/2018, 4:20:37 PM'
> new Date().toLocaleString('en-US');
'1/12/2018, 4:20:42 PM'
```

Not what I was expecting?! I have done a dpkg-reconfigure locales and set it to en-GB. How best to hand locale so I can get the correct date format?

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB');
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US');
```

This two strings select language, but not your location.
Use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and be happy. you can add it to your `locales`

```
const moment = moment;
app.get('*', (req,res,next)=>{
  res.locals.moment = require('moment')
  next()
})
```

and use it even on client side. For example pug-style:

```
- var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
span #{moment().locale(locale).format('LLL')}
```